# Swift Converting Format in Text File (String Parsing)

Tags: swift, string, file, text-files, string-parsing

I was wondering what is the best way to take a text file containing lines in this format: 
**Last_name:First_name:Number_of_cats:Number_of_dogs:Number_of_fish:Number_of_other_pets**

and produce a text file containing lines in this format: 
 
**First_name Last_name:Total_number_of_pets**

For example, it would take a text file containing this:

```
Apple:Tim:0:0:3:0
Jobs:Steve:0:0:5:2
Da Kid:Billie:0:1:0:1
White:Walter:2:1:1:0
Bond:James:2:2:3:0
Stark:Tony:0:1:2:0
Wayne:Bruce:0:0:0:0
```

and output a text file that would look like this:

```
Tim Apple:3
Steve Jobs:7
Bille Da Kid:2
Walter White:4
James Bond:7
Tony Stark:3
Bruce Wayne:0
```

Here's what I've been trying so far without any success:

```
let namesFile = "Names"
let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
      in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

// If the directory was found, we write a file to it and read it back
if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(namesFile).appendingPathExtension("txt") {
    print (fileURL)

    var petSum = 0;
    do {
        let entriesString = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)

        let entries = entriesString.components(separatedBy: "\n")

        for entry in entries {
            let namePets = entry.components(separatedBy: ":")

            if (namePets.indices.contains(1)) {
                var sum = 0;

                print(namePets[1])
                print(namePets[0])

                for namePet in namePets {
                    if let intArg = Int(namePet) {
                        sum = sum + intArg
                    }
                }
                print (sum)
                print ("\n")
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("Failed reading from URL, Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
else {
    print("didn't work")
}

/*
 // Read from the file
 var inString = ""
 // Write to the file named Test
 let outString = "Write this text to the file"
 do {
     try outString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
 } catch {
     print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
 }

 */
```

Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: You could use a regular expression for that and reconstruct a new string from the matches in the new format you want.

Answer (score 0):

- Split the text into lines.
- Map each line

  - Split the line into components separated by colon.
  - Convert field 2 through end to `Int` and sum them up.
  - Return the string in the new format.
- Join the result.

---

```
let text = """
Apple:Tim:0:0:3:0
Jobs:Steve:0:0:5:2
Da Kid:Billie:0:1:0:1
White:Walter:2:1:1:0
Bond:James:2:2:3:0
Stark:Tony:0:1:2:0
Wayne:Bruce:0:0:0:0
"""

let lines = text.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
let convertedLines = lines.map { line in
    let components = line.components(separatedBy: ":")
    return "\(components[1]) \(components[0]):\(components[2...].compactMap(Int.init).reduce(0, +))"
}
let result = convertedLines.joined(separator: "\n")
```